# Can't run app from Eclipse in my htc device

Tags: android, eclipse, htc-android

I'm trying to run my app from Eclipse to my htc Sensation, but in gives me this screen

[image]

It was works in the past and I don't know what happened this time to make it like this.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: r u not able to select the device?

Comment: 1 - close Eclipse
2 - unmount your device from pc
3 - open command line and write adb kill-server
4 - adb start-server
5 - open eclipse
6 - mount your device
7 - run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check

1: USB Debugging is enabled or not

2: OR Check Min SDK version inside the App

3: OR Go to Device Manager check for portable devices and reinstall the driver

4: OR Install the HTC sync

Answer (score 1):

Your app's target version is 4.2 while our htc device is 4.0.3.

Try change target version to 4.0.3 or below.